# Rank organically for content determined by user location rather than by URL

Tags: seo, dynamic

Has anyone had experience with dynamic pages where we load content depending on where user comes from?

From SEO point of view, would it be better to have dynamic single page or to do multiple pages where we would redirect the user depending on where user comes from?

Which approach would be more friendly and what would be your suggestion?

Comment: How many unique pages are you talking about (is is possible to have static pages for each)?

Comment: We are thinking about going to 30 cities in the begining so it would have 30 cities by default. It is possible to have static pages for all of them, but we where wondering if it is necessary to have static pages or we can generate content dynamically depending on where user came from.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have this content to get indexed and ranked by search engines, you need to have separate URLs for different content.

Googlebot crawls from different countries, but Google doesn't have data centers for crawling in every city.   In the US, most of Googlebot's crawling comes from Mountainview, CA which is where Google has headquarters.  With a single URL, Google would only be able to crawl and index your content for Mountainview.

When you do have separate URLs, Google will send users to pages that are appropriate for what they search for.   If somebody from Dallas searches for "Paris", Google will refer them to your Paris page.  It would be bad user experience and it would get you in trouble with Google to redirect them to your Dallas page from your Paris page just because they appear to be located in Dallas.   In other words, search intent should trump the default location.